# How to get request content (body) in PHP?

Tags: php, request

I am sending a request to a php server with a XML in the content:

```
POST /index3.php HTTP/1.0
Connection: Close
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root />
```

I've checked in globals vars (like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_ENV`, `$_FILES`, `$_REQUEST`...) but they are all empty.

How could I retrieve the content in the server?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945879/3995261

Comment: The HTTP `Accept` header "... can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response." Are you saying here that you desire PHP to respond with XML? "... If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types. If an Accept header field is present, and if the server cannot send a response which is acceptable according to the combined Accept field value, then the server SHOULD send a 406 (not acceptable) response." https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Instead of sending the HTTP `Accept` header, I might suggest sending the HTTP `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php):

> **php://input** is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body.

Comment: This needs more hype as it is very important part of a php developer and right now its like a hidden gem

Comment: If `php://input` is a hidden gem, then stream filters for handling encoding would be the entire ring. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-append.php

Answer (score 4):

Use `file_get_contents("php://input")` ([manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)).

In PHP older than 7.0 you could also use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` (depending on [always_populate_raw_post_data](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) setting).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){
    $xml = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $file = fopen("data.xml","wb");
    fwrite($file, $xml);
    fclose($file);
    echo($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.