# How to get body of a POST in php?

Tags: php, rest, post

I submit as POST to a php page the following:

```
{a:1}
```

This is the body of the request (a POST request).
In php, what do I have to do to extract that value?

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

is not the solution, not working.

Comment: This is a helpful question for people looking to create RESTful APIs. Most don't know how to access the raw input data submitted to their scripts as it's not available via the `$_POST` superglobal. This is also (especially) true in the case of PUT requests, as PHP has no corresponding superglobal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get request content (body) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187631/how-to-get-request-content-body-in-php)

Comment: It's worth noting that the name *$_POST* is misleading, as not any type of data from a POST request will be there, but only when the content type is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* or *multipart/form-data*

Answer (score 730, accepted):

To access the entity body of a POST or PUT request (or any other HTTP method):

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Also, the `STDIN` constant is an already-open stream to `php://input`, so you can alternatively do:

```
$entityBody = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

From the [PHP manual entry on I/O streams<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> *php://input* is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use *php://input* instead of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data. *php://input* is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

Specifically you'll want to note that the `php://input` stream, regardless of how you access it in a web SAPI, *is not seekable*. This means that it can only be read once. If you're working in an environment where large HTTP entity bodies are routinely uploaded you may wish to maintain the input in its stream form (rather than buffering it like the first example above).

To maintain the stream resource something like this can be helpful:

```
<?php

function detectRequestBody() {
    $rawInput = fopen('php://input', 'r');
    $tempStream = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    stream_copy_to_stream($rawInput, $tempStream);
    rewind($tempStream);

    return $tempStream;
}
```

`php://temp` allows you to manage memory consumption because it will transparently switch to filesystem storage after a certain amount of data is stored (2M by default). This size can be manipulated in the php.ini file or by appending `/maxmemory:NN`, where `NN` is the maximum amount of data to keep in memory before using a temporary file, in bytes.

Of course, unless you have a really good reason for seeking on the input stream, you shouldn't need this functionality in a web application. Reading the HTTP request entity body once is usually enough -- don't keep clients waiting all day while your app figures out what to do.

Note that php://input is not available for requests specifying a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header (`enctype="multipart/form-data"` in HTML forms). This results from PHP already having parsed the form data into the `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: Please note that afaics, the STDIN stream is not available on systems running PHP using CGI, i.e. via mod_fcgid or mod_fastcgi etc.

Comment: but, i am passing variable(as form-data) with the request , how can i access specified value,   i am passing grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass  as form-data body with the request, how will i get grant_type from  " $entityBody"

Comment: according to my test, this `php://input` is empty for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type as well (besides `multipart/form-data`)

Comment: To expand on @scy's response: STDIN is not available, but `php://input` is. So while on (Fast)CGI configurations `stream_get_contents(STDIN)` won't work, `file_get_contents("php://input")` will.

Comment: STDIN is only defined if you are using PHP from the Command Line Interface, or you define STDIN first: define('STDIN', fopen('php://input', 'r'));  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184962/use-of-undefined-constant-stdin-assumed-stdin-in-c-wamp-www-study-sayhello

Answer (score 50):

return value in array

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: In this scenario, you now have to loop through the `$data` associative array to check if each value is encoded the way you desire. The "stream-to-datatype" way of looking at things may be simplistic, but it may not be as efficient as dealing with encoding in the "stream form" using a stream filter. If you are not handling encoding issues and simply sanitizing and validating, you are missing a step.

Comment: it is a very good way to post data from body in php mvc.

Answer (score 21):

A possible reason for an empty `$_POST` is that the request is not `POST`, or not `POST` anymore... It may have started out as post, but encountered a `301` or `302` redirect somewhere, which is switched to `GET`!

Inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to check if this is the case.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19422232/109787 for a good discussion of why this should not happen but still does.

Comment: This question was asked in the context of developing a REST api platform.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? A REST api might just as well find redirects in it's path, that's the issue I had.

Comment: I meant when I asked the question, I was not trying to resolve a bug, but rather trying to figure out how to develop it.

Comment: this hint saved my day. the receiving server has been reconfigured to redirect to https whoch broke some API clients.

Comment: Actually my request was `POST` but after inspecting it was showing that it was `GET`. Once I added a `/` at the end of my URL, it started showing POST. Weird!

Comment: @zackygaurav maybe it was being redirected from the url without / to the one with / ?

Comment: In 2023: if you connected your domain to cloudflare, this can happen because cloudflare url normalization, so make sure you normalize the url before sending it

Answer (score 16):

```
function getPost()
{
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        // when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request
        // NOTE: if this is the case and $_POST is empty, check the variables_order in php.ini! - it must contain the letter P
        return $_POST;
    }

    // when using application/json as the HTTP Content-Type in the request 
    $post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    if(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        return $post;
    }

    return [];
}

print_r(getPost());
```

Comment: What this bit of logic is missing is a test of the value found in the Content-Type header. It does not follow that just because $_POST is empty that JSON must have been submitted, or that if `json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE` is `false`, that an empty array should be returned. What if someone has submitted XML or YAML? Add a test for the Content-Type and go from there.

Comment: Also, the HTTP request method can factor in determining if you want to accept input data. See the `$_SERVER` superglobal for useful values to check.

Answer (score 12):

This is an exemple of how to create a php api with `file_get_contents("php://input")` and used in `javascript` using `ajax` with `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log("done");
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api.php", true);
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
        username: $(this).val(),
        email:email,
        password:password
    }));
```

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$username  =  $data->username;
$email  =   $data->email;
$password  =   $data->password;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [pecl/http](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http) extension installed, you can also use this:

```
$request = new http\Env\Request();
$request->getBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)

Comment: The preferred method for accessing the raw POST data is `php://input`. `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: the answers dont have  so many upvotes as above comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed HTTP PECL extension, you can make use of the [`http_get_request_body()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php) function to get body data as a string.

Comment: function doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

`http_get_request_body()` was explicitly made for getting the body of `PUT` and `POST` requests as per the  documentation http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-get-request-body.php

Comment: (PECL pecl_http >= 0.10.0)