# PUT, DELETE data from Jquery to PHP

Tags: php, rest, jquery

I am trying to use Jquery.ajax() with PUT and DELETE methods and sending some data along with the request but in the php side when printing the request it comes empty.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax.php',
type: 'DELETE',
data: {some:'some',data:'data'},
}
```

In PHP:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

and I get an empty array.
I don't know if it is a jquery or php thing or simply I can't send data that way.
I know DELETE method is meant to be used without sending additional data but here every ajax request is sent to the same script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get body of a POST in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php/8945912#8945912)

Comment: I just want to feel fancy and sofisticated using all methods. if not possible i'll stick to POST

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To retrieve the contents of the HTTP request body from a PUT request in PHP you can't use a superglobal like `$_POST` or `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` because ...

### No PHP superglobal exists for PUT or DELETE request data

Instead, you need to manually retrieve the request body from `STDIN` or use the `php://input` stream.

`$_put = file_get_contents('php://input');`

The `$_GET` superglobal will still be populated in the event of a PUT or DELETE request. If you need to access those values, you can do it in the normal fashion. I'm not familiar with how jquery sends along the variables with a DELETE request, so if `$_GET` isn't populated you can instead try manually parsing the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable or using a custom "action" parameter as suggested by @ShankarSangoli to accommodate outdated browsers who can't use javascript to send a DELETE request in the first place.

Comment: Tanks I didnt know that, here is how I get the request array:
function getRequest(){
$query_str = file_get_contents("php://input");
$array = array();
parse_str($query_str,$array);
return $array;}

Answer (score 4):

I think `DELETE` type is not support by all the browser. I would pass an addtional parameter say `action: delete`. Try this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {  some:'some', data:'data', action: 'delete' },
}
```

Comment: I actually do it that way and works as expected, I was just looking the RESTful way to do it ;)

Comment: The most common way I see this done with RESTful API is `_method=delete`. I expect more developers would be familiar with that.

Answer (score 3):

It might be an browser issue as said in the jQuery documentation:

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/