# how to receive this curl post?

Tags: php, xml, post

What do I have to do on the server page and how to receive this xml file? I'm stuck.
The xml is fine, it is checked with simplexml_load_string.

```
 $var='caca';
 $login_xml ='<xml>'.
         '<action>log_in</action>'.
     '<parameters>'.
         '<username>'.$var.'</username>'.
     '<pass>abdef01</pass>'.
     '</parameters>'.
     '</xml>';

 $URL = "http://myurl.com/login.php/";


 $ch = curl_init($URL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$login_xml");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I removed my answer, because it is incorrect.

Comment: You need to have a variable name for the login xml .. you can't just post xml.  Do you mean to `PUT`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is send as text/xml and not as url-encoded form-data, you can't use $_POST. You have to read the raw request from the php://input stream

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: these seems to work, some formatting i have to do, thanks, sorry for the dupli

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your CURLOPT_POST_FIELDS:
This option, must be an array:

```
...
$data = array('xml' => $login_xml);
...
```

And then:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
...
```

This sends the value 'xml' as post field;

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I print_r($_POST) on server script I still get an empty array. But thanks for your help. Improving incrementally:)