# Read json data from Android with php

Tags: php, android, json

I'm trying to read data from a decompiled application of Android with a php server. I used `wireshark` to understand what types of data the application sends, and the result is:

> {"initType":"first time","parameters":true,"details":................}

I trying to capture this data and insert them in a file with this php code:

```
<?php  
$json = $_POST["initType"];  
$decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);  
if ($decoded === FALSE) {  
    throw new Exception('Bad JSON format.');  
}  
$file_handle = fopen('tmp.json', 'w');  
fwrite($file_handle, $decoded);  
fclose($file_handle);  
?>
```

The file is correctly generated but it's empty. What is the error?

Comment: Why do you decode and then serialize? Can't you just write the `$json` straight away?

Comment: `json_decode()` turns it into an array. You should `fwrite($file_handle, $json);` instead.

Comment: what's a "decompiled application of Android" ?

Comment: why do you write the decoded json object ?

Comment: I tried to make the change but the result doesn't change. Other suggestions?

Comment: @hasmet I have added one more suggestion for the cause of the problem in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$decoded` is an array, use a loop to write it to file or write the encoded JSON to file (`$json`).  Try using this:

```
fwrite('tmp.json', print_r($decoded, TRUE));
```

or:

```
file_put_contents('tmp.json', print_r($decoded, TRUE));
```

**Update (per your comments):**

If you run a `print_r($decoded)` and it prints nothing, there is a problem with the decoding process of the JSON object passed in. I would recommend checking this to make sure it is formatted correctly.  JSON formatting is a strict business and will halt your end goal if you are missing a double-quote or bracket.  Start by echoing out `$json` (`$_POST["initType"]`) and compare the format to examples posted online (just Google "json formatting").  I can tell you that one thing that stands out to me is: `"parameters":true` (from your example above).  I have a strong suspicion that the key `true` should be in double quotes.  If you are positive that the JSON variable is correct syntactically, I don't think I would be of any more help.  Using `json_decode()` to produce an array to very straight forward once you get it right.

Comment: I tried fwrite($file_handle, $json) and fwrite('tmp.json', print_r($decoded, TRUE)), but the result doesn't change. Only the first case the file is generated, so I think it means that `$json` contains no data. Other suggestions?

Comment: Use print_r($decoded) to make sure it is decoded properly and dump the results of the array

Comment: What is the result then when you use print_r?  Is it empty?  Is there content?

Comment: it is empty, there is no data

Answer (score 0):

Don't decode the json at all -this only brings the problem of trying to serialize an array that burmat mentioned in his answer.

Write to the file the json content straight away:

```
fwrite($file_handle, $json);
```

Also, though I am not PHP expert it seems you access the body of the post request wrongly. Please refer to the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945912/1108032).

Comment: I tried: fwrite($file_handle, $json); and fwrite('tmp.json', print_r($decoded, TRUE)); but the result doesn't change. Only the first case the file is generated, so I think it means that `$json` contains no data. Other suggestions?

Comment: @hasmet: have you seen my edit about how you should read the body of post request?