# Get the values of 2 HTML input tags having the same name using PHP

Tags: php, html

Suppose I have the following table:

```
<form  action="bla.php" method=post>
<table class="pv-data">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="id" size="2" value=1 /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="longitude" size="7"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="latitude" size="7"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="id" size="2" value=2 /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="longitude" size="7"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="latitude" size="7"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

I want to assign the values in this table to php variables, so in `bla.php`

if I used     `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` only the last value is taken because there are two input tags that have the same name.

So can I request the 2 values of these tags having the same name into php?

p.s don't tell me to change the name of the input tags, because the table is bit more complicated than that and it has dynamic add rows:
My real code is: http://jsfiddle.net/CchES/9/

Comment: if it "has dynamic add rows", is it possible to simply append a integer value to the name?

Comment: You can't have inputs with the same name otherwise they will overwrite each other in the POST array.

Comment: Actually you are doing it wrong, because 1) Since the rows are dynamic, you can simply iterate via an array using alternate syntax 2) Once PHP encounters the same names, the last remains. So that, there's nothing you can do about it, you have to deal with arrays.

Comment: I know I can use a counter and things like that, but there's another function that will be affected, and will be harder to implement if they have different names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have repeated names, you have to give them array-style names:

```
<form  action="bla.php" method=post>
<table class="pv-data">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="id[]" size="2" value=1 /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="longitude[]" size="7"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="latitude[]" size="7"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="id[]" size="2" value=2 /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="longitude[]" size="7"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="latitude[]" size="7"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

When you do this, `$_POST['id']`, `$_POST['latitude']`, and `$_POST['longitude']` will be arrays containing the values.

Your form processing code can then iterate over these:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['id']); $i++) {
  if (isset($_POST['latitude'][$i], $_POST['longitude'][$i])) { // Make sure both are filled in
    // Do stuff with this row of the form
  }
}
```

Comment: it's giving me undefind index id when I use $id = $_POST['id']

Comment: Is that before or after the user submits the form?

Comment: after he submits the form. how can I assign an array to another array?

Comment: oh I think the syntax was wrong when I used $id = $_POST['id']

Comment: Then that should work as long as the IDs fields are filled in. You can then do `foreach ($_POST['id'] as $index => $id)`

Answer (score 9):

When PHP populates `$_POST`, if multiple pieces of data have the same name, and that name does not end in `[]` then only one will survive to appear in the `$_POST` array.

Rename the fields so the names ends in `[]`.

> don't tell me to change the name of the input tags, because the table is bit more complicated than that and it has dynamic add rows

Being dynamic shouldn't be a barrier to having `[]` on the end of the name.

If you really can't change the name then it might be possible to bypass `$_POST` entirely and parse the raw data ([via `php://input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)) but IIRC, PHP clobbers that when it populates `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

It is not complicated to change the input tags names in that code you have. Just try this:

```
<input type="text" name="id"'+counter+' size="2" value="'+counter+'"/>
```

That way, you will get names like id-1, id-2, id-3...

Comment: I know I can still use other names and things like that, but there's another function that will be affected, and will be harder to implement if they have different names

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understand that there are dynamic rows generating. But it doesn't mean that you can't give the text boxes in each rows different names. You can definitely make it different. I saw your code in jsfiddle. While appending, you just count number of rows in the table and accordingly you, you can +1 to that and store it in a variable. And concatenate this variable in the name of the text box. So, that everytime, it will click add unit, text box in the row will have different name. Thats the correct solution.

Comment: I know I can still use other names and things like that, but there's another function that will be affected, and will be harder to implement if they have different names