# Loop through dynamically created forms using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to insert data from multiple forms with PHP. The problem is, when I insert it using the subimit button on the first form, it only inserts the data from the first form, when I use the button on the second form onwards it does not register any and presents the error "Undefined array key "cod-1 "". I've tried several ways with the help of GPT chat and it's not working.

```
<form action="patCadastro.php" id="form-1" class="formCadastro" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="formCount" value="1">
  <div class="rowForm">
   <div class="colForm">
    <label for="cod">CÓDIGO</label><br>
     <input id="cod-1" type="text" name="cod-1" required>
   </div>
   <div class="colForm">
    <label for="item">ITEM</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="item-1" id="item-1" required>
   </div>
   <div class="colForm">
    <label for="marca">MARCA</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="marca-1" id="marca-1">
   </div>
   <div class="colForm">
    <label for="modelo">MODELO</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="modelo-1" id="modelo-1">
   </div>
   <div class="colForm">
    <label for="condicao">CONDIÇÃO</label><br>
     <select id="condicao-1" name="condicao-1">
      <option value="" title="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="ÓTIMO" title="ÓTIMO">ÓTIMO</option>
      <option value="BOM" title="BOM">BOM</option>
      <option value="REGULAR" title="REGULAR">REGULAR</option>
      <option value="RUIM" title="RUIM">RUIM</option>
      <option value="INSERVÍVEL" title="INSERVÍVEL">INSERVÍVEL</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btnForm">
   <span class="spanBtn"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i><input class="button cadastro" name="submitForm" type="submit" value="CADASTRAR"></span>
   <span class="spanBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><input class="button moreItem" type="button" value="+ITEM" onclick="moreForm()"></span>
  </div>
 </form>
 <div id="newForm"></div>
```

```
<script>
let formCount = 1;
function moreForm() {
    formCount++;
    const newForm = document.getElementById('newForm');
    const morePats = document.createElement('FORM');
    morePats.method='POST';
    morePats.action="patCadastro.php";
    morePats.classList.add('formCadastro');
    morePats.id = `form-${formCount}`;

    morePats.innerHTML = 
    
    <input type="hidden" name="formCount" value="${formCount}">
    <div class="rowForm">
        <div class="colForm">
            <label for="cod">CÓDIGO</label><br>
            <input id="cod-${formCount}" type="text" name="cod-${formCount}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="colForm">
            <label for="item">ITEM</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="item-${formCount}" id="item-${formCount}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="colForm">
            <label for="marca">MARCA</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="marca-${formCount}" id="marca-${formCount}">
        </div>
        <div class="colForm">
            <label for="modelo">MODELO</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="modelo-${formCount}" id="modelo-${formCount}">
        </div>
        <div class="colForm">
            <label for="condicao">CONDIÇÃO</label><br>
            <select id="condicao-${formCount}" name="condicao-${formCount}">
                <option value="" title="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="ÓTIMO" title="ÓTIMO">ÓTIMO</option>
                <option value="BOM" title="BOM">BOM</option>
                <option value="REGULAR" title="REGULAR">REGULAR</option>
                <option value="RUIM" title="RUIM">RUIM</option>
                <option value="INSERVÍVEL" title="INSERVÍVEL">INSERVÍVEL</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div> ;
    newForm.appendChild(morePats);
</script>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitForm'])) {

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['formCount']; $i++) {

            $cod = $_POST['cod-' . $i];
            $item = $_POST['item-' . $i];
            $marca = $_POST['marca-' . $i];
            $modelo = $_POST['modelo-' . $i];
            $condicao = $_POST['condicao-' . $i];
            $timeStamp = time();

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO patrimonio (id, item, marca, modelo, condicao, lastCheck) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $cod, $item, $marca, $modelo, $condicao, $timeStamp);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        header("Location: patCadastro.php");
        exit();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: did you debug? `echo <pre>; print_r($_POST); echo </pre>;` before the for loop. Also do you have typo in the question or the running code as well, shouldn't the data in `morePats.innerHTML` be enclosed in backticks?

Comment: the typo is only in the question, i new in this and had some problems in make this question.

Comment: The result of debug
Array
(
    [formCount] => 2
    [cod-2] => 04
    [item-2] => ITEM 4
    [marca-2] => MARCA 4
    [modelo-2] => MODELO 4
    [condicao-2] => BOM
    [local-2] => LOCAL 4
    [ue-2] => UE 4
    [valor-2] => 123,12
    [aquisicao-2] => 2023-01-01
    [cor-2] => COR 4
    [submitForm] => CADASTRAR
)
Warning: Undefined array key "cod-1", "item-1", "marca-1", "modelo-1", "condicao-1" on line 25 to 29
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'id' cannot be null in .../patCadastro.php:72 ...
The code identify the form-2 but not the 1.

Comment: So if you have already submitted the first form and then submitting the second form, would the variable `cod-1` exist if your loop starts from 1? Multiple ways to handle it, either add a hidden value as to which form it is and write php code as per that, otherwise make your loop check if the variable exists or not otherwise move to next.

Comment: Instead of using names like `cod-1` and `cod-2`, use array-style names: `name="cod[]"`. Then `$_POST['cod']` will be an array of all the `cod` inputs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344379/get-the-values-of-2-html-input-tags-having-the-same-name-using-php/17344480#17344480

Answer (score 0):

you can add the attribute `form` to new inputs; this attribute attaches your input to the form.

For example, change your JavaScript like this:

```js
<script>
let formCount = 1;
function moreForm() {
    formCount++;
    const newForm = document.getElementById('newForm');
    const morePats = document.createElement('FORM');
    morePats.method = 'POST';
    morePats.action = "patCadastro.php";
    morePats.classList.add('formCadastro');
    morePats.id = `form-${formCount}`;

    morePats.innerHTML = `
        <input type="hidden" name="formCount" value="${formCount}">
        <div class="rowForm">
            <div class="colForm">
                <label for="cod">CÓDIGO</label><br>
                <input id="cod-${formCount}" type="text" form="${morePats.id}" name="cod-${formCount}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="colForm">
                <label for="item">ITEM</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="item-${formCount}" form="${morePats.id}" id="item-${formCount}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="colForm">
                <label for="marca">MARCA</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="marca-${formCount}" form="${morePats.id}" id="marca-${formCount}">
            </div>
            <div class="colForm">
                <label for="modelo">MODELO</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="modelo-${formCount}" form="${morePats.id}" id="modelo-${formCount}">
            </div>
            <div class="colForm">
                <label for="condicao">CONDIÇÃO</label><br>
                <select id="condicao-${formCount}" name="condicao-${formCount}" form="${morePats.id}">
                    <option value="" title="" selected="selected"></option>
                    <option value="ÓTIMO" title="ÓTIMO">ÓTIMO</option>
                    <option value="BOM" title="BOM">BOM</option>
                    <option value="REGULAR" title="REGULAR">REGULAR</option>
                    <option value="RUIM" title="RUIM">RUIM</option>
                    <option value="INSERVÍVEL" title="INSERVÍVEL">INSERVÍVEL</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>`;
    newForm.appendChild(morePats);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `for` only works if it matches the target element's `id`.