# AJAX POST request in JSON login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I'm trying to create a very simple login form using AJAX for server comunication and PHP as a server-side script.
As a starting point I was just trying to send the login data to the server via JSON, but it already gave me issues.

Problem is, when I send the data with a POST request in AJAX my server doesn't seem to get anything and returns no data at all.
Here's the HTML for the request:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Login experiment </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function AjaxJSON() {
    $("form#loginForm").submit(function() {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var jsonlogin = "{\"username\" : \"" + username + "\" , \"password\" : \"" + password + "\"}";
        var str = 'json=' + jsonlogin;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            // URL of my PHP script
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: str,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Data received!" + data);
            }
        });
        // ajax
        })
    })

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> LOGIN: </h1>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"> USERNAME <br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"> PASSWORD <br>
<input type="submit" class="button positive">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML code should simply send the request form (username+password) coded in a JSON string to the PHP script.
The script is something like this:

```
<?php
$result = json_decode($_POST['json']);
echo $result->username;
echo " ";
echo $result->password;
?>
```

Why doesn't it show me any reply?
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Don't try to build JSON by mashing together strings. Browsers have `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are claiming that you are sending `application/json; charset=utf-8`. This is an issue for two reasons:

1. PHP doesn't have any build in methods for handling JSON encoded POST data so `$_POST` won't be populated
2. Your data isn't JSON. It is (improperly escaped) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (which includes a string of (improperly escaped) JSON as one of its pieces of data)

If you want to send JSON, then:

- Build it using `JSON.stringfy` not by mashing together strings
- Don't stick `json=` on the front of it
- Get the data out of the POST body [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

If you aren't tied to JSON, then just use the standard methods for encoding form data:

- Forget the `jsonlogin` line
- Don't override the default `contentType`
- Pass an object of your data to the data argument: `data: { username: username, password: password }`

---

Your next problem is that you are saying `dataType: 'json'` but your PHP is returning (invalid) HTML (that PHP is vulnerable to XSS attacks too).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I will try the JSON.stringify method and check better the contentType and dataType fields :)