# Retrieve JSON via PHP REST API

Tags: php, json

I have this cURL function that send json to a REST API:

```
$url = "https://server.com/api.php";
$fields = array("method" => "mymethod", "email" => "myemail");

$result = sendTrigger($url, $fields);

function sendTrigger($url, $fields){  
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curlResult["msg"] = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlResult["http"] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $curlResult;
}
```

On the server, I have this code:

```
$data = json_decode($_REQUEST);
var_dump($data);
exit();
```

When I execute the cURL command it returns me this:

```
Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

How's that?

Thanks.

Comment: Mixed up `json_encode` with `json_decode`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get body of a POST in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

Comment: Because `$_REQUEST` is most always an array, even if empty. Your JSON blob doesn't appear in there, but `php://input`.

Comment: Do you mean `$result`, not `$_REQUEST`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not using one of the form-encoded content types, PHP will not populate data into `$_POST`.

You need to get your JSON payload from PHP raw input like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes a string and converts it into an object.  The `$_REQUEST` variable is a global variable that contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE` (see [PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)).  Most likely, you have a typing error in your code and you probably meant to use `$request` instead of `$_REQUEST`.