# Convert boolean to integer value php

Tags: php, integer, boolean, type-conversion

Is there any builtin function for PHP that will take a boolean value and return its integer equivalent? 0 for FALSE, 1 for TRUE?
Of course you can easily create a function to do so, I'm just asking if there is a builtin function inside of PHP. I already tried `intval()` and casting it to `(int)` but they didnt work, they return 0 in both cases of TRUE and FALSE.

Edit : the problem was that it wasnt really a boolean, it was a string "false", "true", php didnt detect the jquery post that it passed a boolean. problem solved, thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you're using intval() on a Boolean value, and not on a string containing 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'?

Comment: `echo (int)TRUE;` - If this returns 0 for you, then you have something very very broken

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP has already determined that the problem was their misreading of data types

Answer (score 108):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

`$myInt = (int)$myBoolean` should work

Answer (score 31):

Just add a "+" before your variable like this :

```
$myBool = true; 

var_dump(+$myBool);

ouputs: int(1);
```

Answer (score 20):

```
// cast to Integer
echo (int)true;         // 1
echo (int)false;        // 0

// get the integer value from argument
echo intval(true);      // 1
echo intval(false);     // 0

// simply echoing true returns 1
echo true;              // 1

// you can even add those values
echo true + true;       // 2
```

Comment: While this does get the point across...it wouldn't hurt to add a sentence or two to explain.

Comment: but `echo false;` doesn't return `0`

Comment: @FlashThunder it does not

Comment: in case you're thoroughly confused like I was - check your data types! see some of the other comments -  ENV vars can get processed as strings, which results in eg `echo (int)"true"; // 0` & `echo (int)(bool)'false'; // 1` - fix this by using eg `0` or `1` instead of true/false

Answer (score 8):

If you are unsure of the data type see the example below, it works on strings, integers and booleans.

```
<?php

$options = [ TRUE, FALSE, 'true', 'false', 1, 0, '1', '0', 'on', 'off', 'yes', 'no' ];

foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    $bool = filter_var( $option, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ); // TRUE or FALSE
    print (int) $bool . ' '; // 1 or 0
} 
// Outputs: 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 

?>
```

filter_var( $var, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) will return bool(true) or bool(false) then simply cast as integer.

[filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)

filter_var — Filters a variable with a specified filter

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting your value in from JSON I.E. Via an AJAX POST, the value will come in as a string (As you have found). A way around this is to compare the true/false string and then cast the bool to an int

```
$requestBool = $_REQUEST['bool_value']; //This is 'true' or 'false'

$myInt = (int)($requestBool === 'true');
echo $myInt;

//returns: 0 or 1
```

Comment: Similar way to do it:

`$myInt = ($requestBool === 'true') ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Your answer is very simplicated, first, to receive JSON one should parse POST BODY (eg here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945912/340142). Second JSON by itself can hold values `true`, `false` and `null`. Just to see yourself run this in browser's console `JSON.stringify({one:true, two:false,three:null})`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple castings in a single go:

```
$isTest = 'true';

(int)(bool)$isTest

echo $isTest; // this outputs 1
```

Comment: Yes, but (int)(bool)'false' outputs 1 also

Answer (score -3):

Use type casting (bool):

```
var_dump((bool) 1);         // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) 0);         // bool(false)
```

Comment: Perhaps next time, try reading the question - OP is talking about the reverse of this, casting Booleans to Ints, not Ints to Booleans

Comment: he wants it other way around bool > int