# how to accept two correct answers in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database

I have four choices and two of them can be both the correct answer.

```
if($isCorrect == "answer1"){
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer1', '1')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer2', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer3', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer4', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    $msg = 'You questions has been succesfully added!';
  header('location: addQuestions.php?msg='.$msg.'');
exit();
}
if($isCorrect == "answer2"){
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer2', '1')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer1', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer3', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer4', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    $msg = 'You questions has been succesfully added!';
  header('location: addQuestions.php?msg='.$msg.'');
exit();
}
if($isCorrect == "answer3"){
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer3', '1')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer1', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer2', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer4', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    $msg = 'You questions has been succesfully added!';
  header('location: addQuestions.php?msg='.$msg.'');
exit();
}
if($isCorrect == "answer4"){
    $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer4', '1')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer1', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer2', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer3', '0')")or die(mysql_error());
    $msg = 'You questions has been succesfully added!';
  header('location: addQuestions.php?msg='.$msg.'');
exit();
    }
}
```

when i run these, only one gets accepted as the correct answer.

[image]

Is there any way for my database to accept two correct answers? I am using enum (0,1) to check for the correct answers.

Comment: post your table structure and explain what you want to do - its not clear atm

Comment: Just like @amdixon said, it would be best if you post your table structure, some sample data and expected output. Also include what you have tried so far.

Comment: edit: added the codes

Answer (score 0):

Someone will probably reply later with a better answer, this is just to get the ball rolling.

I would start by refactoring what you currently have to something like the following:

```
// note: there are a lot of ways to make the following cleaner (use an array, 
//   write a function, etc.), but for the sake of time and simplicity I'll
//   leave it at this 

// if $isCorrect == "answer1", $answer1Correct = '1', else $answer1Correct = '0'
$answer1Correct = ($isCorrect == "answer1" ? '1' : '0');
$answer2Correct = ($isCorrect == "answer2" ? '1' : '0');
$answer3Correct = ($isCorrect == "answer3" ? '1' : '0');
$answer4Correct = ($isCorrect == "answer4" ? '1' : '0');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer1', $answer1Correct)")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer2', $answer2Correct)")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer3', $answer3Correct)")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer4', $answer4Correct)")or die(mysql_error());
$msg = 'You questions has been succesfully added!';
header('location: addQuestions.php?msg='.$msg.'');
exit();
```

I don't know what you were using `$sql2` for, I've ignored it here.

**so far, this should do the same as what you currently have**

Then, to make the change you're looking for, I would change `$isCorrect` from string to an array of strings.

For example, suppose answer 1 and 4 are both correct:
    $isCorrect = array('answer1', 'answer4');

Then you use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) so your `$answer1Correct` section becomes:

```
// if "answer1" is in the $isCorrect array, set $answer1Correct to '1', otherwise set it to '0'
$answer1Correct = (in_array("answer1", $isCorrect) ? '1' : '0');
$answer2Correct = (in_array("answer2", $isCorrect) ? '1' : '0');
$answer3Correct = (in_array("answer3", $isCorrect) ? '1' : '0');
$answer4Correct = (in_array("answer4", $isCorrect) ? '1' : '0');
```

---

**Edit:** more improvements

instead of using the ternary operator (`condition ? true_value : false_value`), you can [convert a boolean to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074332/convert-boolean-to-integer-value-php), then convert that to a string.

`(int)true` returns the integer 1, and `(string)(int)true` returns the string '1'.

So your $answer1Correct section becomes: 
    $answer1Correct = (string)(int)in_array("answer1", $isCorrect);
    $answer2Correct = (string)(int)in_array("answer2", $isCorrect);
    $answer3Correct = (string)(int)in_array("answer3", $isCorrect);
    $answer4Correct = (string)(int)in_array("answer4", $isCorrect);

But all of this is a bit tedious to copy+paste so much, a more [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) option is to replace `$answer1Correct` with a function:

```
function answerIsCorrect($answerNumber, $allCorrectAnswers) {
  return (string)(int)in_array("answer" . $answerNumber, $allCorrectAnswers);
}
```

And then your queries become:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', '$answer1', answerIsCorrect(1, $isCorrect)")or die(mysql_error());
```

And now you can do the whole thing as a loop, so **your entire script can be shortened to**:

```
function answerIsCorrect($answerNumber, $allCorrectAnswers) {
  return (string)(int)in_array("answer" . $answerNumber, $allCorrectAnswers);
} 

$answers = array(
  1 => $answer1,
  2 => $answer2,
  3 => $answer3,
  4 => $answer4
)

for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES ('$lastId', $answers[$i], answerIsCorrect($i, $isCorrect)")or die(mysql_error());
}
```

if you change `$isCorrect` from a string to an array of strings, as above.