# Form Hub Data Exorter

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the website is hosted by Web Server. I use PHP and Mysql. And I also register and upload my data in formhub.org. Formhub allow us to export data to CSV.

My purpose, I want to automatic import the latest CSV file in Formhub or mean the latest data to my Mysql Database.

So When I upload data from Smart Phone through the customize From in Formhub.org, It will automatically update to my web base online.

How Could I do? Who can help me? Please Please give me the best solution and suggestion for this purpose.

Comment: I hope I will get best solution and great suggestion to do what my purpose is!

Comment: until now no one suggest my question..so bad

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the REST services formhub provides?
info at https://github.com/SEL-Columbia/formhub/wiki/Posting-To-External-Site

In this way, each form data is stored to your formhub and also by POST to a script anywhere you like and you can process it in your php (e.g your own mysql db).

with php you can collect the data with 
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
like explained here: [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)