# Artisan::call('migrate') not working after upgrading Laravel to 4.2

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using  **Artisan::call('migrate');** in a Laravel controller method and it working while Laravel version was 4.1. After updating Laravel using **composer update** command (and setting  **"laravel/framework": "4.2.*"** in composer.js) this controller method (as this is the only command in it) doesn't work anymore.

I've even added **'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256** in /app/config/app.php as stated in  http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.2

That already happens: http://laravel.io/forum/06-02-2014-not-able-run-artisan-commands

When I put Artisan::call('migrate') into try/catch block controller looks like this:

```
public function ArtMigr(){
    try {
            Artisan::call('migrate');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }   

}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Use of undefined constant
>   STDIN - assumed 'STDIN'' in
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:112
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(112):
>   Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Use of undefine...',
>   'D:\htdocs\artis...', 112, Array) #1
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(49):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->doAsk(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion)) #2
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(186):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->ask(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion)) #3
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\ConfirmableTrait.php(21):
>   Illuminate\Console\Command->confirm('Do you really w...') #4
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand.php(59):
>   Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->confirmToProceed()
>
> ## 5 D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(112):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() #6
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php(252):
>   Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput)) #7
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(100):
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput)) #8
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(96):
>   Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput)) #9 [internal
>   function]: Illuminate\Console\Application->call('migrate') #10
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Artisan.php(57):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #11
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(208):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Artisan->__call('call', Array) #12
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(208):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Artisan->call('migrate') #13
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\app\controllers\HomeController.php(160):
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('call', Array) #14
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\app\controllers\HomeController.php(160):
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('migrate') #15
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\app\controllers\HomeController.php(145):
>   HomeController->InstallDatabaseStructure() #16
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\app\controllers\HomeController.php(127):
>   HomeController->WriteDatabaseCredentials('localhost',
>   'laravel-aplikac...', 'root', '') #17 [internal function]:
>   HomeController->postTestDatabaseConnection() #18
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(231):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #19
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(93):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('postTestDatabas...', Array)
>
> ## 20 D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(62):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(HomeController),
>   Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'postTestDatabas...') #21
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(930):
>   Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
>   Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'HomeController',
>   'postTestDatabas...') #22 [internal function]:
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}() #23
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(105): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array) #24
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(996):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #25
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(964):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 26 D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(738):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 27 D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(708):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> ## 28 D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
>   1, true) #29
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47):
>   Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
>   1, true) #30
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51):
>   Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
>   true) #31
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23):
>   Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1,
>   true) #32
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(606):
>   Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #33
>   D:\htdocs\artisan_error\public\index.php(49):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run() #34 {main}

Is everything done properly on my side?

composer.js contains:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: check this

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184962/use-of-undefined-constant-stdin-assumed-stdin-in-c-wamp-www-study-sayhello

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem actually with the last version,all previous sources are not working, should use :

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--force' => true));
```

Tested and working fine.

Comment: This was the working answer for me running Laravel 4.2.

Comment: On Laravel 7 throws a fatal error saying --force option is not permitted

Answer (score 3):

`Use of undefined constant STDIN` seems to be a Symfony error, see [github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10795](http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10795).

A `composer update` should fix your problem.

Comment: @mpet, show us what your `composer.json` looks like. Put it in your original post.

Comment: @mpet, change `minimal-stability` to `RC` (or `beta` if that doesn't work), the change for the Symfony issue was pushed to `2.5.0-RC1` release.

Comment: but the right question is why it happens while using Laravel 4.2 using default values

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add a `'-n'=>true` to your call

since you are in production and a "are you sure question is fired"

so it will be like

`Artisan::call('migrate',array('-n'=>true));`

Answer (score 2):

A bit of information on this topic, for anyone that comes across this:

This happens because the `migrate` command in a production environment will ask for confirmation. This is however not possible in the context of a web request, so the command fails. To stop it from asking for confirmation, use the `--force` flag.

The error `Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN` is basically symfony telling you it has no standard input that it can use to query user input. This is expected behavior if you're not running the command in a terminal. This behavior still exists in the current version of `symfony/console` (5.0.* as of writing).

Also please note that trying to manually define STDIN as proposed in http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10795 won't work in this case.