# PHP returning empty POST array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

JavaScript jQuery post:

```
var animals = {
    animalsArray: [],
    tripId: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
};

$('.student-check').each(function() {
    animals.animalsArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

var sendMe = JSON.stringify(animals);

$.post("saveChanges.php", sendMe, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, "json");
```

PHP handler:

```
echo json_encode(print_r($_POST, true));
// Array
// (
// )
```

Why is the array empty? I'm posting data but the response returns an empty array.

Comment: try json_encode($_POST, true);

Comment: What happens if you just `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encoding the data as JSON, which isn't a format PHP handles natively for form submissions.

Remove `var sendMe = JSON.stringify(animals);` and pass `animals` to `$.post` instead of `sendMe`. jQuery will encode it using one of the standard formats supported by HTML forms and PHP.

Alternatively see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php) for how to get the raw request body.

---

Also:

```
echo json_encode(print_r($_POST, true));
```

`json_encode` and `print_r` are both functions that take a data structure and express it as a string. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to say access the tripId inside the animals object, would I go about doing that like $_POST['tripId']?