# How to Extract Request Body at Server Side in PHP send by Retrofit POST request

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit Lib.

**My code is**

```
public class TestPostData {
  final String username;
  final String password;

  TestPostData(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

**and interface is**

```
    interface Test {
      @POST("/post.php")
      void testMethod(@Body TestPostData postbody,@Query("qName") String qName,Callback<Response> callback);
  }
```

**Rest Adapter**

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(TEST_URL)
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
    .build();
```

and call it as

```
testObj.testMethod(new TestPostData("myusername", "mypassword"),"myname",new Callback<Response>() { ..............
```

at the server side i get $_POST array as empty. How to get username and password value at server side. I get the name value.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little bit late, but to read the request body in PHP you can do:

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```

More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have done this in other way. I will check this in my next project.

Comment: @JoginderSharma how did you made the other way?