# AJAX is not passing values to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can't find a solution to this simple problem of accessing variable passed to my PHP script via AJAX. I have even tried isset($_POST) but it still fails to find the username and password variables.

Here is the AJAX call:

```
var u = $("#username", form).val();
var p = $("#password", form).val();

//testing
console.log('Username: '+u); // 'John'
console.log('Password: '+p); // 'test'

if(u !== '' && p!=='') {

    $.ajax({url: 'http://www.domain.net/php/user-login.php',
    data: {username:u,password:p},
        type: 'post',                   
    async: true,
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
        $.mobile.loading('show'); // This will show ajax spinner
    },
    complete: function() {
        // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
        $.mobile.loading('hide'); // This will hide ajax spinner
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //save returned data to localStorage for manual button toggling later
        //window.localStorage.setItem('topGenderDataArray',data);
        console.log("Login successful: "+ data);
        console.dir(data);

        alert("Welcome back "+data['username']);
        $("#loginButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    },
    error: function (xhr,request,error) {
        // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action   
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again! '+xhr+ " | "+request+" | "+error);
    }
});
```

Here is the beginning of the PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
else{
    $data['message']= "Sorry, an error occurred! []";
    $data['user_id']= -1;
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What does this print: `console.log("Login successful: "+ data);`?

Comment: [object] the next line prints the object's properties...which are always "Sorry, an error occurred! []" and -1

Comment: What does the network tab show in developer tools?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in your php code 
you do the echo `json_encode($data)` inside the `else` clause, while you should do it after the `if` and `else` just like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
else
{
    $data['message']= "Sorry, an error occurred! []";
    $data['user_id']= -1;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: No, this is just the first section of the PHP script that will check if the data is there then continue.

Comment: I suggest you to put the echo inside the `if { }` not the `else { }`

Answer (score 1):

This contains your answer:

[How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

you are postin json data. User and password are not in the _POST array. They are in the request body. You need to json parse it

Comment: Sorry for typos Posting answers on my mobile :)

Comment: Not sure why, but it works now all of a sudden... All I did was retype in 'json' for the datatype in the ajax call and it started working....makes no sense so I think it must have been my web server screwing up.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to print the `$data` after the `if and else statement`

Like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
}
else
{
    $data['message']= "Sorry, an error occurred! []";
    $data['user_id']= -1;
}
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
?>
```

After is will work properly.