# Posting JSON encoded data via php & cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I can't send JSON encoded data via PHP & cURL

my sender code is:

```
$id = 1;
$txt = "asdsad";
$txt2 = "baszama";
$data = array("id" => "$id", "txt" => "$txt", "txt2" => "$txt2");
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

index.php:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

My recerieved data:

```
array(0) { }
```

What's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP expects `key=value` pairs in the submitted data when it's building the GET/POST/REQUEST superglobals. You're sending a bare string, which has no key. No key, no array entry in the superglobals.

Try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "foo=$data_string");

$_REQUEST['foo']
```

Alternatively, since you're sending via POST, you could use

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and simply read in the raw text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending request as JSON string, then you will have to read it as a string:

```
$json = json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

You will find more information here: [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)