# PHP foreach loop with checkboxes

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Hi i have a number of checkboxes in a form

```
<p>Select the modules you take:<br/>
Business <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="Business"/><br />
Accounting <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="Accounting"/><br />
Marketing <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="Marketing" /><br />
</p>
```

I have a response page and expect the user to choose multiple answers so how would i use a foreach loop? I've tried the following but no hope

```
foreach($modules as $selected){
print "The modules were ".$modules;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those curly quotes `“` part of your actual code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No - edited it

Comment: Thanks, I needed to be sure. Many actually have those as their actual quotes and we often tell them that it will throw/cause an error.

Comment: Have you tried Stepashka's answer below? Plus, make sure you have form tags with a POST method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my form is fine, i just want to avoid using the [] at the end of the names

Comment: well, you can't achieve this without using an array; not in PHP anyway. can you explain why?

Comment: I can't help not knowing why you want to do this without using an array. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Your checkboxes should have name with [] at the end. In this case they will automatically transform to array in PHP.

i.e.

```
<p>Select the modules you take:<br/>
Business <input type="checkbox" name="modules[]" value="Business"/><br />
Accounting <input type="checkbox" name="modules[]" value="Accounting"/><br />
Marketing <input type="checkbox" name="modules[]" value="Marketing" /><br />
</p>
```

php code:

```
echo "The modules were: "
foreach($_POST['modules'] as $selected) {
    echo $modules." ";
}
```

or as simple as

```
echo "The modules were: ".implode(", ", $_POST['modules']).".";
```

Please note that if user doesn't select any checkbox $_POST['modules'] will be undefined. You need to check it first before use. it is also a good practice to validate user's input before usage.

Comment: hi my names do not have square brackets at the end. How would i do it without them?

Comment: You edit your code and add them in.

Comment: @MariM i want to avoid using that method

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that @spymaster. It is the only *correct* way to do it.

Comment: There is a low-level way of doing it... @spymaster you can get the raw post data using this advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php and parse it manually. Dat will contain something like '... &modules=Business&modules=Accounting& ...' But I do not see any reason why anybody want to do it in this simple case.