# How to send json from android to php?

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

To post json from android to php, i used Volley library `StringRequest` object.

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // some code
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //some code
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                ArrayList<Command> commands = MyApplication.readFromPreferences(getActivity(), Constants.COMMAND);
                String jsonCommands = new Gson().toJson(commands);
                params.put("commands", jsonCommands);
                return params;
            }
        };
```

And to catch the data in php and verify if it was sent correcttly, I used this

```
echo $_POST["commands"];
```

*Output:*

```
[{\"product\":{\"category_id\":1,\"created_at\":\"2015-06-13 17:49:58\",\"description\":\"CF77 COIN FINDER\",\"url_image\":\"IMG_76ECDC-707E7E-70AC81-0A1248-4675F3-F0F783.jpg\",\"name\":\"CF77 COIN FINDER\",\"pid\":12,\"price\":500.0},\"product_quantity\":3},{\"product\":{\"category_id\":1,\"created_at\":\"2015-06-13 17:49:58\",\"description\":\"JEOSONAR 3D DUAL SYSTEM\",\"url_image\":\"IMG_2D9DF0-2EB7E9-ED26C0-2C833B-B6A5C5-5C7C02.jpg\",\"name\":\"JEOSONAR 3D DUAL SYSTEM\",\"pid\":15,\"price\":500.0},\"product_quantity\":1},{\"product\":{\"category_id\":1,\"created_at\":\"2015-06-13 17:49:58\",\"description\":\"MAKRO POINTER\",\"url_image\":\"IMG_Macro.jpg\",\"name\":\"MAKRO POINTER\",\"pid\":18,\"price\":500.0},\"product_quantity\":3}]
```

I have noticed that when sending the json string with POST Method using Volley library, a lot of anti-slashes have been added to escape double quotes.

*So here comes my problem:*

I want to decode json to an array of objects in php, so i used

```
$commands = json_decode( $_POST["commands"],true);
```

But it always returns an empty array because of the invalide above json (caused by the anti-slashes).

Is there a method in php or in java SDK providing a contract for sending and receiving json without having this kind of problems? Or should i reformat the json in php and delete all the anti-slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem using a custom `json_decode` method in order to clean the json string before decoding it.

```
function json_clean_decode($json, $assoc = false, $depth = 512, $options = 0) {
    // search and remove comments like /* */ and //
    $json = preg_replace("#(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|([\s\t]//.*)|(^//.*)#", '', $json);
    // search and remove all backslashes
    $json = str_replace("\\","", $json);

    if(version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=')) {
        $json = json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth, $options);
    }
    elseif(version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        $json = json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth);
    }
    else {
        $json = json_decode($json, $assoc);
    }

    return $json;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to send the json data in the URL parameters.

You need to override the `getBody()` method to return the json data as request body, not as url parameters.

Eg:

```
/**
 * Returns the raw POST or PUT body to be sent.
 *
 * @throws AuthFailureError in the event of auth failure
 */
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return new Gson().toJson(commands).getBytes();
}
```

And then in PHP you can:

`$jsonRequest = json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN));`

Comment: Can you provide an example of using the `getBody` method?

Comment: And How to get the json in php?

Comment: Updated the answer again. A more explicit answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php

Comment: The problem that i have other params to post them as follow `Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("lastName", lastName.getText().toString().trim());                            
                            ArrayList<Command> commands = MyApplication.readFromPreferences(getActivity(), Constants.COMMAND);
                            String jsonCommands = new Gson().toJson(commands);
                            params.put("commands", jsonCommands);`

Comment: You can post other params as url params, unless they are  too large. Then you'd have to extend the request/response body representation to support more complex structures.

Answer (score 1):

first there is problem with the json itself is not build correctly is better to [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for this, for example:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
try {
       js.put("value",10);
} catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
String jss = js.toString();
```

you can check if the parse is success by copy the string and copy it in online parser like this http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: I have checked that and it was a problem of the `anti-slashes`. But i want to use volley library because it is more flexible and easy to use.

Comment: Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); this line is very problematic, what about other types? maybe try to change to <Object> anyway i recommend that add only one parameter and send it to the server and see what happen, i still think is better to use the JSONObject is more solid...

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method to send json to web service.

```
public String makeServiceCallSubmit(String url, int method,
            JSONArray object) {

        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(object.toString()); 
              //  se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                httpPost.setEntity(se); 
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } 
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            Response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Response;


    }
```

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated. But thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: If this answer fullfill your need then please mark true to the answer.

Comment: My problem isn't  about posting the json, instead it is about how to ensure that the json sent from android is valid so that i can decode it in php.