# Send data (POST or GET) to server with Volley Lib in Android

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I've developed a Application that i'm going to send data from the phone to the server by `Json`, to do this i use **`Volley`** Library in Android.
but i can not send data to the server!

my simple php code :

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
$j = array('name' =>$name);
echo json_encode($j);
```

my java code :

```
    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://my-site-name/sampleGET.php";

        StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, 
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("result:", response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("err", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    makeJsonObjectRequest();
                }
            }
        ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", "json");
                return params;
            }
        };
        mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

It also got help from the link below : [Click to see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948191/send-post-request-using-volley-and-receive-in-php)

But still could not use it and send data (POST or GET) from mobile to server!!!
How can I do this?

Comment: If your network connection fails, you'll enter a recursive loop - remove  makeJsonObjectRequest(); - in the onErrorResponse method.

Comment: Without any logs etc. I'd be inclined to say you could try $_SERVER["name"] instead of $_GET["name"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised on [How to send json from android to php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024436/how-to-send-json-from-android-to-php/31024620#31024620)

From current code, remove this method:

```
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name", "json");
            return params;
        }
```

And override the `getBody()` method instead. Then, adapt it to return the json data that you need as request body based on the below sample:

```
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        try {
               js.put("fieldName", "fieldValue");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return js.toString().getBytes();
    }
```

And then in php to decode your json data:

```
    $jsonRequest = json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN));
    var_dump($jsonRequest);
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.