# Angular - send HTTP post data to server [HOW TO]

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to send data from my login FORM to backend writen in PHP using POST method.

my Angular code looks like:

```
$scope.getToken = function(){
    // console.log $scope.login to make sure I'm not sending empty data
    console.log($scope.login);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../../api/v1/Oauth.php',
        data: { 'login' : $scope.login, 'password' : $scope.password }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
};
```

and after that I try to catch it on my PHP:

```
if((isset($_POST['login']) AND isset($_POST['password'])))
{
    $username = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo $username;
}
else
    var_dump($_POST);
```

This statement always go to else and return empty array.
Can someone advise me what I'm doing wrong or how can I debug this?
Because it looks that I send data fron angular correctly but it didn't come to server.

Thanks
Kind Regards
Andurit

Comment: can you open up the developer tools and examine the request body. Does it look like what you expect?

Comment: Did you mean `'username' : $scope.username` instead of `'login' : $scope.login ?`

Comment: hey @Komo good point, anyway this should atleast dump data in else statemenet which is not doing. 
But thanks I will edit this (+ THUMB UP for you )

Comment: @pQuestions123 reuqest looks like:  { login: "Andurit"
password: "ads" } which looks fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Check your network tab in your developer bar. You can see that you send payload data in the http body. That's why the $_POST array is empty.

Comment: Marked, was just waiting until it let me do it

Answer (score 2):

Some older server side web libraries like Coldfusion/.NET/PHP have issues grabbing a POST BODY by default (which is how `$http` sends the data).

You can reference [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php) to learn how to write your PHP in a way that it will accept the current and correct standard of sending data via a post.

> To access the entity body of a POST or PUT request (or any other HTTP
>   method):

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

> Also, the STDIN constant is an already-open stream to php://input, so
>   you can alternatively do:

```
$entityBody = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

Comment: Hey @Sean Larking , I already accept Henris answer, howwever thumbup for you for this explenation :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
data: { login : $scope.login, password : $scope.password }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post('url', {login: 'Alex', password: 'qwerty'}).then(function(){},function(){});
```

Comment: if this, dont work, find problem on the server.

Small recommendation, for http create service/factory.