# $http.post in AngularJS

Tags: php, json

I'm completely new to webdev and i need to use AngularJS.
I really have troubles with using $http.post.

```
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.search = function() {
        $http.post('server.php', { "data" : $scope.keywords})
        .success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.result = data;
        })
    };
```

I use this controller (and it works fine), but i would like to pass a second parameter (a string) to `server.php`, in addition to `$scope.keywords`.

How do i do that, both on server and client side ?

Comment: $http.post('server.php', { "data" : $scope.keywords,"anotherData":anotherData})

Comment: Ok, but how do i use anotherData on the server.php file ?

Comment: In the server side you'll have some parameters on the $_SERVER or $_POST variables, check for them there. They''ll likely be a json, just *json_decode* them.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you be more precise ? I'm really new to webdev as i said. How do i access the parameters of the $_POST variable ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php

Comment: $_POST['data'] and $_POST['anotherData']

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for.

Comment: @olivierGrech, I have posted this answer.

Comment: Voted, sorry for the wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would post :

```
$http.post('server.php', { "data" : $scope.keywords,"anotherData":anotherData})
```

And receive data:

```
$_POST['data'] and $_POST['anotherData']
```

Answer (score 0):

post call expects path which is `server.php` and body a JSON object

what you can simply do is use JSON.stringify(*any json abject*).

e.g.       `JSON.stringify({
                data: $scope.keywords,
                otherStuff: otherStuff
            })`

that s it i suppose.