# How to read a JSON message from the HTTP header in PHP

Tags: php, json, http-headers

I am sending a JSON request from one PHP file to another like this.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/2.php");       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req_json);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($req_json))                                                                       
);

//execute post
$res_json = curl_exec($curl);

//close connection
curl_close($curl);
```

I am just trying to get the JSON request sent to this 2.php

```
$req_json = stream_get_contents("php://input"); 
echo $req_json;
```

But, I am getting the below error.

> Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Can anyone tell me how to get the JSON message from the HTTP body? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$req_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $req_json;
```

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)