# insert values to mysql using php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am inserting some values from my android login page to mysql database using php .

**login.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abc","xyz") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sync",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_mobile_no = $_POST['user_mobile_no'];
$user_email_id = $_POST['user_email_id'];
$imei_no = $_POST['imei_no'];
$login_date = $_POST['login_date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

$user_name = 'Navdeep';
$user_mobile_no = '12345678990';
$user_email_id = 'nav@gmail.com';
$imei_no = '1234567890';
$login_date = '24-12-2012';
$time = '01:01:01';

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  
login_details(user_name,user_mobile_no,user_email_id,
    imei_no,login_date,time)  
VALUES('$user_name','$user_mobile_no','$user_email_id','   $imei_no','$login_date','$time')");

if($result)
{
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User Details inserted successfully";

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "There was an error inserting user details";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

When i use `$_POST['']` values are getting inserted as blank , but when i hardcode the values it is getting inserted , need some help

**Android code :**

```
try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("user_name",userName);
        jsonObject.put("user_mobile_no",mobNo);
        jsonObject.put("user_email_id",email);
        jsonObject.put("imei_no",imeino);
        jsonObject.put("login_date",date);
        jsonObject.put("time",time);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        String basicAuth = "Device " + new 
        String(Base64.encode((imeino).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        RequestBody body = 
        RequestBody.create(JSON,String.valueOf(jsonArray));
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().header("Authorization", 
        basicAuth).url(url).post(body).build();
        Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Request to the 
                        server failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws  
            IOException {
                Log.i("response ", "onResponse(): " + response );
                StatusLine statusLine = null;
                String result = response.body().string();
                if(result.equals("") || result.equals(null)){
                    Log.i("No response", "No response");
                }else{
                    Log.i("Response","Response "+result);
                    statusLine = StatusLine.get(response);
                    final int responseCode = statusLine.code;
                    Log.d("Code:", String.valueOf(responseCode));
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It you're sure you data is being passed correctly, then you add a content type header "Content-Type", "application/json"; charset="utf-8"; to that request. Also make sure you are receiving your json object or array correctly on your server side. Else, try volley, makes all of this seamless

Comment: Plus on use server side, your receiving json, so I don't think I can get the data that way, try $payload = file_get_content('php://input');  $request = json_decode ($payload); then you can do $username = $request->user_name; send that as a response n see if I can pick it up on or app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send form data request from android.
Replace this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("user_name",userName);
        jsonObject.put("user_mobile_no",mobNo);
        jsonObject.put("user_email_id",email);
        jsonObject.put("imei_no",imeino);
        jsonObject.put("login_date",date);
        jsonObject.put("time",time);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        String basicAuth = "Device " + new 
        String(Base64.encode((imeino).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        RequestBody body = 
        RequestBody.create(JSON,String.valueOf(jsonArray));
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().header("Authorization", 
        basicAuth).url(url).post(body).build();
```

With

```
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("user_name",userName)
            .add("user_mobile_no",mobNo)
            .add("user_email_id",email)
            .add("imei_no",imeino)
            .add("login_date",date)
            .add("time",time)
            .build();

String basicAuth = "Device " + new 
        String(Base64.encode((imeino).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
    Request request = new Request.Builder().header("Authorization", 
            basicAuth).url(url).post(formBody).build();
```

Comment: This worked thanks , but what is the reason that the jsonarray did not work ?

Comment: you are adding raw data in body, so you are not able get data using $_POST . How to get raw post data in PHP check this post and you can convert your php script only to work not from android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php