# How to read AJAX POST request data and deal with Notice: Undefined index: data in?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending data with ajax in Prestashop 1.6 with this function:

```
 function setWineoCarrierMethod(method_id){
      var methodData = {
        'ajax_function': 'set_wineocarrier_method',
        'method_id': method_id
      };
      var jsonData = JSON.stringify(methodData);
      if (method_id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: baseDir + '/modules/wineocarrier/ajax.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: jsonData,
                dataType: 'json',
          success: function(json) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
            console.log("successfull request");
          },
          error: function(json) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
            console.log("error in the request");
          }
        });
      }
    };
```

I want to read the data in the ajax.php file using:

```
 $data = $_POST['data'];

 $data2 = $_REQUEST['data'];
```

Both are returning lots of html and there is a notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: data in ... line 12 which is  $data =
>   $_POST['data'];

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but this *might* be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php  Essentially I think you're looking for the "POST body", not individual POST values.

Comment: Did you try it without stringifying the data

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` use in php u will get the solution, because there is no data index in your ajax post

Comment: @adeneo I have but the result is the same.

Comment: @devpro This is the solution. Thank you!