# Error in retrieving json fields sent by POST to PHP script

Tags: php, json, http, post, request

I am working first time with PHP and Http Post method. I have written a PHP script and running it on WAMP server. I am testing this script using the Advanced Rest Client for chrome. Following is my PHP script

```
 <?php

    var_dump($_POST);

    $m             = new MongoClient();
    $db            = $m ->tododb;
    $collection    = $db->tasks;

    $title         = $_POST['title'];
    $description   = $_POST["description"];
    $priority      = $_POST["priority"];
    $status        = $_POST["status"];

    $tmp = array(
        "title"         => $title,
        "description"   => $description,
        "priority"      => $priority,
        "status"        => $status
    );

    $collection->insert($tmp);

    echo "success";
?>
```

[Screenshot of my Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bO7Q.jpg)

But i am getting error in my response. For every index variable in $_POST "Undefined Index" error occurs.
Further, on doing var_dump on $_POST i found that the array is empty. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code and/or Post request.
[Screenshot of erroraneous response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D896S.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get body of a POST in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

Comment: ***For every index variable in $_POST "Undefined Index" error occurs...*** What would want to say with that? You might as well ***C-P*** (*Copy-Paste*) the exact Error Message here **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$var=$post ['var'];
```