# react.js using axios to post data to php, but php echo empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reactjs, axios

I am using react.js, axios, and PHP to post data to MySQL database

This is my react.js code

```
sendData(){
var data = new FormData();
data.append('name', 'jessie');
data.append('time', '12:00');
data.append('food', 'milk');
data.append('nutrition', 'vitaminA');
axios.post(
'./sendData.php',{
  data: data

})
.then(response => {
console.log(response)
console.log(response.data)
this.filter = response.data
})
.catch(e => {
this.errors.push(e)
})
}
```

And this is my PHP code

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "mydb";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully yayaya";
echo "the post after this";
echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```

And this is my Chrome Console

```
Connected successfully yayayathe post after this[]
```

I don't know why my PHP get empty data and echo empty value.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [axios docs](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON.

One option is to [read json from the body in your PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945912/1633510):

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Then there's no need to wrap your data in `FormData`, you can just add it directly:

```
axios.post(
'./sendData.php',{
  data: {
    name: 'jessie',
    time: '12:00',
    food: 'milk',
    nutrition: 'vitaminA'
  }
})
```

---

Another option is to set the `Content-type` header in axios:

```
axios.post(
  './sendData.php',{
  data: data
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }
})
```

---

Option 1 seems better to me though

Comment: I use option 1, but it also console Connected successfully yayaya[]

Answer (score 1):

Try to take json from phpinput it is halpfull for me:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer
but my chrome Console me 

Connected successfully yayaya{"name":"jessie"}<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/foodMaster/build/sendData.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
Array[]

not all data been echo

Comment: @ZakChen ok, good, now try to debug input data, and echo some variants with json_decode and not, you need to take json string and then decode it

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hack, make proper code for your project.

First of all install this [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) node package in your project. Then you can you `stringify` your data using this function and submit data to the server.

`axios` already clear that issue on its documentation file. You can check [using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) link for more info.

Whatever is use the easy way to resolve this issue in my scenario, here is my code:

```
var qs = require('qs');  
var palyload = {
    'command': 'userLogin',
    "email" : this.state.email,
    "password" : this.state.password,
};
axios.post( apiBaseUrl, qs.stringify(palyload) ).then(
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

then you PHP server show proper global data like as below:

```
Array
(
    [command] => userLogin
    [email] => asdf@test.com
    [password] => af12548@$
)
```