# PayPal Webhooks in Sandbox not working (Null Data)

Tags: php, paypal

I'm having issues with setting up webhooks with PayPal.

Actions Taken:
I have set up a hook to alert me of completed payments.
I do notice that PayPal does hit the requested url.  However when I do a complete log of $_POST, $_Get and $_COOKIES there is nothing sent.

My understanding as that the server is meant to send data in the POST form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

---

Update:  Solution to this FOUND!!!

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request_body = json_decode($request_body);
$request_body = print_r($request_body, true);
```

I found that PayPal posts the JSON string a different way other then via POST.  The above code is how I was able to retrieve the required data.

Thanks again guys for the input.

Comment: Have you tried hitting your endpoint in postman the way you expect PayPal to be sending it?

Comment: are you getting the paypal return object, if so you you print that and check!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php

Comment: Yeah I'm doing a $post_data = print_r($_POST, true); and dumping the out put to a file which is showing blank arrays.

Comment: I found the solution, please see update above.  Thanks again guys.