# Trying to POST an array from front end to php. The connection opens but doesnt send data.

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

So I am capturing data from an API and storing it in an array that looks like this: `stackVar[{user, red, 12}, {user1, green, 13}]`

Then I am trying to send that with _POST. After testing I realized I am in fact saving the array properly because console.line(stackVar) works. I also noticed that I am opening the connection to the php file but it closes the connection before posting any data to the php page. Here is what my front end looks like.

```
if(results.length == stackVar.length){

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://www.server.com/saveF.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(JSON.stringify(stackVar));
}
```

and my back end.

```
<?php   $conn = new mysqli($sn, $un, $pw, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$bInfo = $_POST["stackVar"];
$infoEncoded = json_encode($bInfo);
$getsome = $infoEncoded[0][0];
$sql = "INSERT INTO companies(company) VALUES ('$getsome')";
echo $getsome;



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close()
?>
```

Comment: Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: As regards your actual problem, I think you mean `json_decode($bInfo);` instead of `json_encode($bInfo);`. You are receiving a JSON string from the client, so you want to _decode_ it from JSON into an object. Encoding is the process of translating from a (PHP) object into a JSON string. Check the docs.

Comment: You have two basic problems here. (1) You are sending JSON but are claiming to be sending form encoded data. Your content-type should be `application/json` not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. (2) This is covered in the duplicate question.

Comment: And you say " it closes the connection before posting any data to the php page"...what happens then? Have you watched your browser's network tab  and console to see what is sent/received, what errors are thrown? I doubt it would just do what you describe without showing some sort of error.

Comment: @ADyson — `$_POST["stackVar"]` will be undefined.

Comment: Good lord man!! I hope this isnt live.

Comment: @Quentin good point, but I think they will still have the problem I described once they resolve that.

Comment: To get json body you must use ```json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))```. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php

Comment: @ADyson Yes I meant json_decode. That was an typo on me when I was typing this out but the real code says json_decode. let me try looking at the duplicate question to see if it doesn't help.

Comment: @RadekPech I am new to PHP can you explain to me what 'php://input' represents? Is that the information being transferred or do i need to change the name?

Comment: @krizpers You must use this exactly as written. The ```php://input``` is a special url-like filename that says you want to read the request body that cannot be automatically parsed by PHP (JSON, XML, etc.). See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php