# RAW (JSON) POST data arrives as NULL or EMPTY ARRAY

Tags: php, post

Im trying to make a REST API with PHP and I've got a problem **receiving POST data**, if i send it with a form, it arrives perfectly fine.
But when i try to send it with Content-Type application/json **it arrives as empty array**.

Here is the code that receives the data:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
die(var_dump($data));
```

the data is sent with Boomerang REST client.

This are the HEADERS of the request:

```
POST /miel/api/inscripcion-tutoria HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Origin: chrome-extension://eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
Cookie: PHPSESSID=b586e11ef9d81...bd992603a; _ga=GA1.1.20...67.151250
```

The response is this one:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 07 Dec 2017 15:49:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) PHP/7.1.7
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.7
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Notice that Content-Length is 0, and when y execute the var_dump the data is completely empty.

I've also tried with this:

```
die(var_dump($_POST));
```

That last example only works when I send the data with a FORM like

```
<form action=http://localhost/miel/api/inscripcion-tutoria method=post >
```

In case of the form the content type is

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Content length in the response headers are the same.

But if I change the content type in the boomerang REST client and put it like the one sent in the form it doesn't work neither.

I tried with the variable `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and the var_dump returned NULL.

Any clue on the solution would be very appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `true` for the parameter `use_include_path` in `file_get_contents`? Maybe this post helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php

Comment: @dbrekelmans think the true is on the `json_decode`

Comment: You are diagnosing several things at the same time and you have no way to know which one is failing (though it's surprising that var_dump() does not produce any output, not even `NULL`). Why don't you test `file_get_contents()` and `json_decode()` separately?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot it, it returns NULL sometimes, 
and with the following lines it returns 

` string(0) "" `

`$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($entityBody);die;`

Comment: Then it's clearly what you said in the question title, though you said empty *array* (I've fixed the title). In any case, the request headers include `Content-Length: 0`. Are you positively sure data is being sent in the first place?

Comment: Yes im sure, data appears on the query string parameters of the request, and for some reason that I dont understand `Content-Length: 0` appears also in the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form request which works perfect. 
I just tried with the variable `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and the var_dump returned NULL.

Comment: Query string? Then you aren't sending data in the request **body**.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found the solution to the problem. It was very simple and a matter of inexperience.

When you send a request with POSTMAN or Boomerang or any other REST client, **the data must be on the body of the request**.

I was using the empty fields of the "PARAMS" given by the client, but those are meant to add items to the URL, not to make a data structure for the body.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch your data using:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

In **POSTMAN Rest Client**, Select "`Body`" which gives you options to add parameters to `Request Body`.

Select **Raw** and paste your **JSON**.

Make sure the `Content-Type` **Header** of your request is set to "`application/json`"

[image: request body pass json data]

Comment: also found this article helpful: https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/