# How to send a serialized array to a php document?

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a JavaScript array named seat with many values in it.

As follows,I've serialized to be sent to a php file named confirm.php.

```
$('btnsubmit').click(function() {
  var seat = [];
  var seatar = JSON.stringify(seat);
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "confirm.php",
    data: seatar
  })
})
```

And this is the code in my php file.

```
$seatarr = "";
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $seatarr = $_POST["data"];
    print_r($seatarr);
}
```

I've tried with my level best, looking at the previous questions asked on this section. But no matter how hard I try to fix it, this code never works. Why not?

Comment: It should be `type: "POST"` and not `method`

Comment: $('input[name="btnsubmit"]') ??

Comment: @Dario: [`method` was added in jQuery v1.9.0](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 4):

You're just sending raw JSON, but you're expecting to get a URI-encoded form with a `data` field in it. You can get that if you change your `ajax` call to use `data: {data: seatar}`:

```
$('btnsubmit').click(function() {
  var seat = [];
  var seatar = JSON.stringify(seat);
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "confirm.php",
    data: {data: seatar}
  })
});
```

jQuery will automatically turn that object into a URI-encoded submission with a single field in it.

Then use `json_decode` if you want to parse it on the server:

```
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $seatarr = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
    print_r($seatarr);
}
```

**Also**, as [Mr. Blue pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113726/how-to-send-a-serialized-array-to-a-php-document/50113752?noredirect=1#comment87244526_50113726), your button selector is probably incorrect. You have `$('btnsubmit')` which is looking for a `<btnsubmit>...</btnsubmit>` element. You probably meant `$("#btnsubmit")` (if you have `id="btnsubmit"` on the button) or `$("[name=btnsubmit]")` (if you have `name="btnsubmit"` on the button).

Comment: For the OP, you can turn the JSON object in to an associative array via the default parameter that [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes, just set it to true.

Comment: ....alternatively you can leave the javascript as-is and read the raw data on the PHP side - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php

Comment: @symcbean: Indeed, though you'd want to add `contentType: "application/json"` (and fix the selector).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be to rewrite the data like this:

```
seatar = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(seatar);
```

and decode like  T.J Crowder did propose:

```
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $seatarr = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
    print_r($seatarr);
}
```