# How to read peerless header in php

Tags: php

We are sending a POST type http request with information in header as follows:

POST /Inbound_sms_peerless.php HTTP/1.1
        Request Method: POST
        Request URI: /Inbound_sms_peerless.php
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Type: application/json
    User-Agent: Jersey/2.23.2 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_60)
    Host: www.sms.gnyservices.com
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 120
    [Full request URI: http://www.example.com/Inbound_sms_peerless.php]

Request Header : {"from":"+13126477409","recipients":["+19298005992"],"ccRecipients":[],"text":"Sajjad","mediaURL":null,"contentId":null}

My question is how can i read the request header values in php?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the HTTP request headers with [`get_headers()`](http://www.php.net/get_headers).

Comment: Output of get_headers()
try get_headers 
getheaders: 0 => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
getheaders: 1 => Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 21:07:44 GMT 
getheaders: 2 => Server: Apache 
getheaders: 3 => X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
getheaders: 4 => Vary: Accept-Encoding 
getheaders: 5 => Content-Length: 0 
getheaders: 6 => Connection: close 
getheaders: 7 => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

but i don't see any values of the following line
Request Header : {"from":"+13126477409","recipients":["+19298005992"],"ccRecipients":[],"text":"Sajjad","mediaURL":null,"contentId":null}
want to read these

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/8945879/286934 on how to read the request body for POST requests.