# How i can save result from console log to the database?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a completed selection and then there is a table that I fill out as well, then by clicking on the button the selected result goes to the console, but how to save it to the database? Please help me, I really need your help
P.S.  Ajax request is not needed

```
 function submit() {
    $table.find('tr').each(function(){
        var rowValues = {};
        $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
            var value = $(this).find("input").val();
            rowValues[columnNames[i]] = value;
        });
        arr.push(rowValues);
    });

    console.log(arr);

    var selector = document.getElementById('category_select');
    var id = selector[selector.selectedIndex].id;
    console.log(id);

    var selector = document.getElementById('patient_select');
    var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(value);  //How i can save result in db ?
  $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                data: value,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $('#bt').text('OK');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#bt').text('Send');
                alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

my insert.php

```
  <?php 

        $value = $_POST['value'];

        $link = mysqli_connect(
            'localhost', 
            'root',       
            '',   
            'answer_result');     
        if (!$link) {
            printf("ERR: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO answer_result_table (`answer_content`, `patient_id`)
        VALUES ( '$value', '$value')") 
        or die(mysqli_error($link));
            ?>
```

Comment: Do not use query method. Use prepared statements.

Comment: You need AJAX for this, if you want to send data from browser to PHP. You can't mix code like this, php will be executed before the JS.

Comment: I updated the question. please see if ajax and insert are written correctly.

Comment: Have your tried this `method: 'POST'` instead of this `type: 'POST'` in your ajax request.

Comment: and in `insert.php` just `echo $value;` if you see the value in output then you are good to go to next step, just you will need to correct your insert query then.

Comment: In Network writes that he does not understand what such a value is in the insert.php ```$value = $_POST['value'];```

Comment: Try this `$value = $_POST['data'];`

Comment: In your ajax you can change this `data: {value: value}` and then `$value = $_POST['value'];`

Comment: Or instead of what @AkhtarMunir said, use `data: {value:value}` in the ajax. Both are fixes to the same problem.

Comment: So, was this your mistake ?

Comment: Yes, but here's another little question. and in order to convey not only ```value```, but something else, it’s enough just to list through a comma?

Comment: Exactly you can seperate it by commas, like this `data: {value: value, city:city, state:state}` etc....

Comment: So every first variable will be considered as input in this case to access in php code.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir  ```  data: {
                    array_answer: arr,
                    patient_name: value_patient_name,
                },```
I did like this

Comment: @XXXXXX ofcourse you can do it, if you pass array, then don't worry, you need to just access that array variable and play with it in php. Sometimes, when you do form serialize in ajax, it means you submit full form with only one variable.

Comment: @Adder Thanks for referring my answer dear.

Comment: He didn’t see it, because I passed it empty, and when everything is filled, then everything’s okay, just now I want to transfer the array to a string to save it, but json_edcode does not allow me to do this...

Comment: Dear you will need to loop through your array in php and then save it in your db.

Comment: But just convert the array into a string and save how the string will not work?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir  everything, I did everything that I need. Thanks you for help

Comment: @XXXXXX well, you welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with `Ajax request is not needed`.

But I think, that you have to pass that value with AJAX to the Server and let some PHP handle the storage.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best option is that: You have to move php code to separate file and call it via ajax, in request payload you have to place json encoded `arr` and other needed data and place it in POST fields or make one JSON with all data, then you must in php `json_decode()` payload and finally save it to db

Comment: See also [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

Comment: I updated the question. please see if ajax and insert are written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that Javascript (at least in this case) is a client side language, and php server side language.

that's mean, according your code, when the browser request this page, the server runs php and then send to the browser the page with the javascript, that will be executed by the browser itself, and the result of php execution (in this case opens a connection and insert a empty record.)

You can run the js script, print the log to the console, and then send the log to another page where the php code will be executed.
You can do it in sync mode, like a normal redirect, o in async mode, using AJAX.

Comment: I updated the question. please see if ajax and insert are written correctly.