# Passing data via ajax issues

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to pass data to my laravel controller function via Ajax.  At this point I just want to return the data being sent to verify ajax is working. I can "GET" with ajax, but when I try to "POST" ajax brakes.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Here is my ajax code...

```
var startMapLocation = { startCity: "Cleveland", startStat: "Oh" };
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: startMapLocation,
            success: function(data, status) {
                //alert(data);
                console.log("success:", data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Ajax Broke!" + status);
            }
        });
```

My laravel function is...

```
public function postphp( Request $request)
    {
         $a = $request->all();

         $city = $a["startCity"];

        return json_encode( $city );
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

Comment: `dataType: "json"` missing i think

Comment: Suggest more information on the error message

Comment: I'm getting a 405 error "Method Not Allowed".  I'm not sure why I couldn't post. This works with straight up PHP but not with laravel.  Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for your help. To resolve this issue, I first had to verify that my route was a post route not a get route.

Route::post('/postphp', 'GSResultController@postphp');

I also need to get my csrf-token and add it to the ajax call.

```
headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
            },
```

This fixed my problem.