# pushHTTP and php - How to?

Tags: php, http, push

i'm trying to record some data from Orange LiveObjects. A Lora Module sends to Orange some data. Then a pushHTTP request is sent to my URL (...../add.php).
Here is the code stored in this url :

```
<?php
$svg = fopen("essai.txt",a);    // open file 'essai.txt' to store data received
$x=time().chr(10).chr(13);      // print timestamp in file essai
fwrite($svg,$x);                
                                // try to wrtite each $_POST item
foreach($_POST as $cle=>$valeur) {
    $x='     '.$cle.'=>'.$valeur.chr(10).chr(13);
    fwrite($svg,$x);
}
// write separator in file
$x='---------------------------------------------------'.chr(10).chr(13);
fwrite($svg,$x);
// close file
fclose($svg);
?>
```

What I get in the "essai.txt" is something like that timestamp which means tha I do receive the HTTP request but no data :

```
1585829024
---------------------------------------------------
1585832024
---------------------------------------------------
```

Impossible to store any data from Live Objects.
Where am I wrong ?
Thanks for any piece of idea !

Comment: Maybe it is called as a GET request, then $_POST is empty. You could use $_REQUEST to maintain both cases.

Comment: Unrelated note: instead of `chr(10).chr(13)` just write `"\r\n"`.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php