# Using Php, how can I access a Java Script Object I've passed by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php

So, as I explained above, I would access (using PHP) an object that I've created using JS and then I've passed to .php by using Ajax. I've heard about json, it can be useful or can I work without that?
I'm linking my code:

```
    var data = {
     v_Post: document.getElementById("v_Post").value,
     x: document.getElementById("x").value,
     y: document.getElementById("y").value,

      }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:80/mySite.it/scripts/script.php",
      data: "data=" + data,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(v) {
        alert("Chiamata riuscita!!!");
          },
      error: function(){
        alert("Chiamata fallita!!!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried to do this in php, but it seems not to work:

```
   $data = $_POST['data'];
   echo '<script>console.log($data.v_Post); </script>';
   echo $data.v_Post;
```

Comment: I don't see the necessity of json with the ajax request.  You could simply provide the data to `data`, and then in php all three keys would be accessable on the `$_POST` associative array

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an object, which you are converting to a string (`"[object Object]"`) so the actual data is being lost before you send it to the PHP.

Just pass jQuery the object itself, without converting it to a string:

```
data: data,
```

Then jQuery will use the standard Form Url encoding which PHP will decode automatically and use to populate `$_POST`.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo $_POST['v_Post'];
?>
```

It will then be available in the JS:

```
success: function(response_data) {
     alert(response_data);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check, `"data=" + data` evaluates to `data=[object Object]`, due to the way objects are coerced to strings when concatenated. So that's not what we want.

Indeed, JSON can help, as it forms a nice, uniform interface for complex data. Also, you don't want to specify parameter encoding yourself (`data=...` as a string), as jQuery can do it for you, if you just pass an object containing parameters. I've also taken the liberty to rename the parameter to `payload`, so we don't have two different things both named `data` and confusing the answer. You would use it this way:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: {
    payload: JSON.stringify(data)
  },
  ...
});
```

and then in PHP,

```
$payload = json_decode($_POST['payload']);
```

We could also send JSON directly as a POST request body, not as a POST parameter, but PHP is not really nice about accessing that. You can see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php).

However, you don't have a complex data structure, you have three flat variables - and that can be transferred simply as three POST variables. In that case, this suffices:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: data,
  ...
});
```

and in PHP:

```
$v_Post = $_POST['v_Post'];
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
```

Comment: Why are you sending data encoded as JSON wrapped in a one dimensions Form Url Encoded packet? Just use one or the other.

Comment: @Quentin: I believe the edit I wrote in the meantime addresses that.