# jquery ajax post mix array objects send empty array to php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I send an array / object mix to Php but the POST is empty

console.log (data)

```
data:
    ABONNR: 900000064
    UMO301NR: 173088
    change:
        assistant: [phone: Array(0)]
        patient: [phone: {…}, social: "single"]
        patient-medical: "Hoge bloeddruk"
        patient-name: "Burger Maria SENSO2ME"
    remove:
        assistant: [{…}, phone: Array(0)]
        patient: [phone: Array(0)]
        patient-medical: "Evenwichtsproblemen"
```

Jquery

```
var json = {data:changed}
console.log(json)
 $.ajax({
   url: Settings.base_url + '/home/update',
   data: json, 
   type: 'post',
   success: function (response) {
    console.log(response)
   }
});
```

Php print_r($_POST)

```
Array ( )
```

Do you have an idea ?
Thx!

Comment: `var jsonData = {data:data}` and `data: jsonData,` use this..

Comment: Logged `data` has a key `change`, while in your AJAX you try to send `data:changed`. I assume you were looking to send `data: data.change`.

Comment: what does console.log(json) gives you ?

Answer (score 0):

**$_POST[]** will not grab `JSON`. You should use **file_get_contents()** instead.

```
 // Takes raw data from the request
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json);
```

similar answer there: [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php/8945912)

Comment: var_dump($data), return NULL

Comment: what does console.log(json) gives you ?

Comment: see below the console.log

Answer (score 0):

```
ABONNR: 900000064,
UMO301NR: 173088,
change:
    assistant: {
        phone: []
    },
    patient:{
        phone:
            [current: "22222222222", prev: ""],
        social: "single",
        patient-medical: "Dementie",
        patient-name: "Burger Maria SENSO2ME"
},
remove:
    assistant: {
        0: {name: "WZC Gitschotelhof Loopwacht+"},
        phone: []
    },
    patient: {
        phone: [],
        patient-medical: "Kan niet alleen recht bij val"
    }
```