# PHP Get the body response

Tags: javascript, php, http, request

I'm trying to send API response from my Javascript file like this:

```
try {
  await fetch('https://example.com/api', {
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: 'john',
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the body of the request.
My Backend Server built on PHP.
I have already seen this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php).
As I saw there, I need to do this:

> To access the entity body of a POST or PUT request (or any other HTTP method): `$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');`

This is my `Index.php` file:

```
<?php

$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo json_encode($entityBody);
```

And it returns nothing.
[image]

I'm new to PHP so maybe its a stupid mistake.

My goal is to print `john` in the console.

Comment: `$entity_body` is already a JSON string, you don't need to call `json_encode()`. You would call `json_decode()` to convert it to a PHP array or object.

Comment: What do you see as the raw response in the Network tab of the browser?

Comment: If I try to decode it it shows me this error: `JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF`.

Comment: I'm using React Native so I cant see the Network tab like browsers.

Comment: Check what your PHP script actually received. If you have no way of inspecting the request client-side, then write the contents of `php://input` to a file on the server, and then check what that contains after.

Comment: It shows nothing in the file. I have created a basic HTML with this script to check it on client-side, and it shows nothing, there is no response.